# eBay affiliate - tracking an order status

Tags: javascript, html, ebay-api, affiliate

I was a partner to eBay, and I am advertising eBay products on my website.

Here is my question:

If a user redirects to eBay from my website and purchases a product, can we get the order/purchase id of that particular purchase and can we track it's status and show it in my website.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? I am trying to track my advertising products on other websites and I need to find a way to track

Comment: I didn't find any way to do it.